# How do I access different buttons in flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

So this is my login page, and I have a login button that logins the user. However, I wish to add a "Home" button that when pressed, would redirect the user to the index.html page. However, I'm unsure of how to approach this.

**In my app.py flask file:**

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
                login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
            return '<h1>Invalid username or password</h1>'
        elif request.form['home'] == 'Home':
            print("Home pressed")
            return render_template('index.html')
        
        #return '<h1>' + form.username.data + ' ' + form.password.data + '</h1>'
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

**In my login.html:**

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">

      <form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="/login">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ wtf.form_field(form.username) }}
        {{ wtf.form_field(form.password) }}
        {{ wtf.form_field(form.remember) }}
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
        <input type="submit" name="home" value="Home">
      </form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
{% endblock %}
```

[image: Here's how the login page looks like]

Comment: why aren't you using two routes for two different purpose?

Comment: @HashirIrfan How would that be?

Comment: <a href="{{url_for(app.index)}}" >Home</a>
In /index route redirect to index.html